# remove padding from accordion

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I have a mdbootstrap accordion inside an angular component. By default, it has some padding. I wish to make it smaller. From inspecting the accordion I see that it's made out of a button that has the padding. So in the `.scss` file of the component where I use the accordion, I do:

```
accordion-button {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

But it doesn't do anything with and without `!important`. I checked if the `.scss` file even works by changing random title color and it does. I think that my value if being overwritten. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to add your css rule to the /scr/styles.scss file?

Comment: @altgov3en Yes, doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
::ng-deep .accordion-button {
    border-radius: 0!important;
}
```